# Can not access front camera in iOS in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

**  I am new in flutter and developing a face detection application. For this I have created  a page where user will take image from camera. I have added a flip button here to switch front and back camera. Initially rear camera is working well but when I switch to front camera, app crashes but I can not get the proper crash issue from terminal. Please help me. I will be grateful to you. Thank you.**

```
  import 'dart:convert';
            
            import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
            import 'package:facedetection_ios/dashboard.dart';
            import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
            import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
            import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
            import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
            import'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
            import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
            
            
            class CheckIN_cameraPage extends StatefulWidget{
             final String empID,hospitalID;
              const CheckIN_cameraPage({Key? key, required this.cameras, required this.empID ,required this.hospitalID}):super(key : key);
              final List<CameraDescription>? cameras;
              @override
              State<CheckIN_cameraPage> createState()=> _CheckIn_CameraPage();
            }
            
            class _CheckIn_CameraPage extends State<CheckIN_cameraPage>{
              late CameraController _cameraController;
              bool _isRearCameraSelected = true;
            
              @override
              void dispose() {
                _cameraController.dispose();
                super.dispose();
              }
            
              @override
              void initState() {
                super.initState();
                initCamera(widget.cameras![0]);
              }
            
              Future<void> requestLocationPermission() async {
                var status = await Permission.location.request();
                if (status.isGranted) {
                  // Permission granted; you can now get the location.
                } else {
                  // Handle permission denied or restricted.
                }
              }
            
            
            
              Future<LatLng> getCurrentLocation() async {
                try {
            
                  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
                    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
                  );
            
                  LatLng latLng = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
            
                  return latLng;
                } catch (e) {
                  print('Error getting current location: $e');                                  
                  return const LatLng(0, 0); // Return a default location in case of an error.
                }
              }
            
            
              Future takePicture() async {
                if (!_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
                  return null;
                }
                if (_cameraController.value.isTakingPicture) {
                  return null;
                }
                try {
                  await _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
                  XFile picture = await _cameraController.takePicture();
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //     context,
                  //     MaterialPageRoute(
                  //         builder: (context) => PreviewPage(
                  //           picture: picture,
                  //         )));
                  //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()),);
                  requestLocationPermission();
            
            // Get the current location's LatLng.
                  LatLng currentLatLng = await getCurrentLocation();
            
                  print('Current Location: ${currentLatLng.latitude}, ${currentLatLng.longitude}');
            
                  if(currentLatLng.latitude == null && currentLatLng.longitude == null ){
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: 'Please turn on location',
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    );
                  }else{
            
               DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                    String formattedDate = "${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.day}";
                    DateTime timenow = DateTime.now();
                    String formattedTime = "${timenow.hour}:${timenow.minute}:${timenow.second}";
            
                    Map<String, String> bodyData = {
                      'empID': widget.empID,
                      'hospID': widget.hospitalID,
                      'date': formattedDate,
                      'time': formattedTime,
                      'longitude': currentLatLng.longitude.toString(),
                      'lattitude': currentLatLng.latitude.toString(),
                      'action': 'IN',
                    };
            
                    String fileField = 'Selfie.png'; // Name of the field for the file in the request.
                    String filePath = picture.path; // Replace with the actual file path.
            
            
                    sendRequestWithFileAndBody('https://frans.secuodsoft.com/mapi/attendance', bodyData, 'image', filePath);
                  }
                } on CameraException catch (e) {
                  debugPrint('Error occured while taking picture: $e');
                  return null;
                }
              }
            
              Future initCamera(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
                _cameraController =
                    CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.medium,imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420);
                try {
                  await _cameraController.initialize().then((_) {
                    if (!mounted) return;
                    setState(() {});
                  });
                } on CameraException catch (e) {
                  debugPrint("camera error $e");
                }
              }
            
              Future<void> sendRequestWithFileAndBody(
                  String url, Map<String, String> bodyData, String fileField, String filePath) async {
                var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
            
                // Add the JSON body to the request.
                request.fields.addAll(bodyData);
            
                // Open the file and create a MultipartFile.
                var file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(fileField, filePath);
            
                // Add the file to the request.
                request.files.add(file);
            
                // Send the request and get the response.
                var response = await request.send();
            
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            
                  String responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();
                  final obj = jsonDecode(responseBody);
                  if(obj['message']=='Employee attendance updated'){
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: 'Face Matched',
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    );
                  }else if(obj['message']=='out of location'){
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: 'Out of location',
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    );
                  }else{
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: 'Face not matched',
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    );
            
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()),);
                  }
                } else {
                  print('Request failed with status code: ${response.statusCode}');
                }
              }
            
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                Color firstBackgroundcolor = const Color(0xFF9A56FD);
                Color secondBackgroundcolor = const Color(0xFF5E22E9);
                Color themeblue = const Color(0xFF541ae5);
                return Scaffold(
                    body: SafeArea(
                        top: true,
                        bottom: true,
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // Full-height container
                            //camera
                            SizedBox(
                              height: double.infinity,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child:  (_cameraController.value.isInitialized)
                                  ? CameraPreview(_cameraController)
                                  : Container(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                                top: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                child: Opacity(
                                  opacity: 0.5,
                                  child: Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    child: Text('Please keep your face inside this square.',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: themeblue, fontSize: 13 ,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ),),
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                            //focus
                            Positioned(
                                child: Lottie.asset(
                                  'assets/rawfile/face.json',
                                  width: 550,
                                  height: 390,
                                  repeat: true, // Set to true for looping
                                  animate: true, // Set to false to stop the animation
                                ),),
                            //flip and camera
                            Positioned(
                              left: 0,
                              right: 0,
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), // Adjust margins as needed
            
                                width: 200.0,
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      child:Container(
                                        width: 55.0, // Adjust the size of the container as needed
                                        height: 55.0,
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                                            colors: [firstBackgroundcolor, secondBackgroundcolor],
                                          ), // Background color
                                        ),
                                        child: const ClipOval(
                                            child: ColorFiltered(
                                              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                                  Colors.white,
                                                  BlendMode.srcIn
                                              ),
                                              child: Image(
                                                image: AssetImage('assets/images/flip.png'),
                                                width: 30,
                                                height: 30,
                                              ),
                                            )
            
                                        ),
                                      ),
            
                                      // Replace with your image path
            
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(
                                                () => _isRearCameraSelected = !_isRearCameraSelected);
                                        initCamera(
                                            widget.cameras![_isRearCameraSelected ? 0 : 1]);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      child:Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                        width: 55.0, // Adjust the size of the container as needed
                                        height: 55.0,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                                            colors: [firstBackgroundcolor, secondBackgroundcolor],
                                          ), // Background color
                                        ),
                                        child: const ClipOval(
                                            child: ColorFiltered(
                                              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                                  Colors.white,
                                                  BlendMode.srcIn
                                              ),
                                              child: Image(
                                                image: AssetImage('assets/images/camera.png'),
                                                width: 30,
                                                height: 30,
                                              ),
                                            )
            
                                        ),
                                      ),
            
                                      // Replace with your image path
            
                                      onTap: () {
                                        takePicture();
                                      },
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
            
            
                          ],
                        )
                    ));
              }
            }
```

Comment: ##This is  error log it is showing          -[NSTaggedPointerString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x850742eab2614503     * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector s